# Filter is not a function in custom pipe angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I'm beginner to Angular 2.
I was trying to create the custom pipe for search operation in angular 2.
While trying to filter the objects of data by using the filter function I was getting as like my data is not supporting the filter function.

My Pipe code :

```
import {Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
  name : 'GenderSetter'
})
export class SettingGenderPipe implements PipeTransform
{
   transform(Employees:any,EmpFind:any):any{

    if(EmpFind === undefined) return Employees;
    else {
      return Employees.filter(function(x){
        console.log(x.toLowerCase().includes(EmpFind.toLowerCase()));
        return x.toLowerCase().includes(EmpFind.toLowerCase())
      })
    }    
   }   
}
```

My template html file :

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" id='txtsearch' [(ngModel)]="EmpFind"/>
  <table>    
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
     <td>Salary</td>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let x of Employees'>
            <td>{{x.Empname | GenderSetter : EmpFind}}</td>
            <td>{{x.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{x.salary}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

My Component Code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
Employees=[
  {Empname : 'Roshan',gender:1,salary:'70k' },
  {Empname : 'Ishita',gender:0,salary:'60k' },
  {Empname : 'Ritika',gender:0,salary:'50k' },
  {Empname : 'Girish',gender:1,salary:'40k' },
]
}
```

In the console I'm getting the error as :
ERROR TypeError: Employees.filter is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying the pipe to the x.Empname, however the pipe itself should accept an array. Move your pipe to the ngFor:

```
  <tr *ngFor='let x of Employees | GenderSetter : EmpFind'>
        <td>{{x.Empname}}</td>
        <td>{{x.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{x.salary}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Huhh, Thanks a lot. Facing one more as like :  x.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: What does the Employees array look like? what values does it contain?

Comment: Edited the code with component code. Please check once please & I'm getting as object as value for x in console.

Comment: Okay, got it. x.Empname should be placed. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Well, objects don't have neither 'toLowerCase()' method nor includes

Comment: Cool, glad to help!